# How can I pre load assets before App load in react native without using expo?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a game in react native and I have lots of graphical objects and images in my screens . so I want to be sure my screens load without delay.

for instance I have a problem with "ImageBackground",
it loads background after my screen rendered an it's not professional.

I searched and I found AppLoading on Expo but I'm not using expo in my project. so could you please help me with some advices?

thanks.